# How to connect to VPN L2TP IPsec in Kubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, vpn, cisco

I have to connect to a Cisco Meraki VPN.

- I am using a fresh installation of Kubuntu 18.04 LTS.
- I was given a public IP, a VPN user, its password and a pre-shared key.
- I opened the network manager and created a new VPN choosing the *Layer 2
  Tunneling Protocol (L2TP) -Compatible with L2TP VPN server-*. I
  filled in the data in their respective fields.

I was able to connect to these kind of VPNs in 16.04 time ago, but when I connect to this one I get errors and as I am a newbie in this subject I cannot understand very well the error messages. This is the syslog (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX means the public IP I have to connect to):

```
Sep 20 12:11:51 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1537438311.1469] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="e08aedcd-7c6c-41ac-92fe-796c04bd5345" name="Cisco Meraki VPN" pid=1009 uid=1000 result="success"
Sep 20 12:11:51 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1537438311.1522] vpn-connection[0x5591977d64c0,e08aedcd-7c6c-41ac-92fe-796c04bd5345,"Cisco Meraki VPN",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 31186
Sep 20 12:11:51 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1537438311.1668] vpn-connection[0x5591977d64c0,e08aedcd-7c6c-41ac-92fe-796c04bd5345,"Cisco Meraki VPN",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Sep 20 12:11:51 H81M-DS2V nm-l2tp-service[31186]: Check port 1701
Sep 20 12:11:51 H81M-DS2V nm-l2tp-service[31186]: Can't bind to port 1701
Sep 20 12:11:51 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: Starting strongSwan 5.6.2 IPsec [starter]...
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: Loading config setup
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: Loading conn 'e08aedcd-7c6c-41ac-92fe-796c04bd5345'
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: found netkey IPsec stack
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.6.2, Linux 4.15.0-29-generic, x86_64)
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-e08aedcd-7c6c-41ac-92fe-796c04bd5345.secrets'
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md4 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic counters
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
Sep 20 12:11:53 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Sep 20 12:11:54 H81M-DS2V charon: 13[CFG] rereading secrets
Sep 20 12:11:54 H81M-DS2V charon: 13[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Sep 20 12:11:54 H81M-DS2V charon: 13[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-e08aedcd-7c6c-41ac-92fe-796c04bd5345.secrets'
Sep 20 12:11:54 H81M-DS2V charon: 13[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Sep 20 12:11:54 H81M-DS2V charon: 15[CFG] received stroke: initiate 'e08aedcd-7c6c-41ac-92fe-796c04bd5345'
Sep 20 12:11:54 H81M-DS2V charon: 07[IKE] initiating Main Mode IKE_SA e08aedcd-7c6c-41ac-92fe-796c04bd5345[1] to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Sep 20 12:11:54 H81M-DS2V charon: 07[ENC] generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
Sep 20 12:11:54 H81M-DS2V charon: 07[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.0.24[500] to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[500] (204 bytes)
Sep 20 12:11:58 H81M-DS2V charon: 04[IKE] sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Sep 20 12:11:58 H81M-DS2V charon: 04[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.0.24[500] to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[500] (204 bytes)
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V charon: 00[IKE] destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA e08aedcd-7c6c-41ac-92fe-796c04bd5345[1] to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: sending packet: from 192.168.0.24[500] to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[500] (204 bytes)
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: sending packet: from 192.168.0.24[500] to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[500] (204 bytes)
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V nm-l2tp-service[31186]: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1537438324.3534] vpn-connection[0x5591977d64c0,e08aedcd-7c6c-41ac-92fe-796c04bd5345,"Cisco Meraki VPN",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1537438324.3568] vpn-connection[0x5591977d64c0,e08aedcd-7c6c-41ac-92fe-796c04bd5345,"Cisco Meraki VPN",0]: VPN service disappeared
Sep 20 12:12:04 H81M-DS2V NetworkManager[570]: <warn>  [1537438324.3578] vpn-connection[0x5591977d64c0,e08aedcd-7c6c-41ac-92fe-796c04bd5345,"Cisco Meraki VPN",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
```

Then I tried to connect with the service `xl2tpd` stopped. The message *Can't bind to port 1701* disappeared but there were new errors, in fact I think the result is worse because I cannot even see the public IP I have to connect to in any message.

I have also tried to fill in the *Phase 1* and *Phase 2* fields of the IPsec settings, as I read in several forums, but I do not even know what to write there, I just copied other answers, so that is a nosense.

Can anyone help me to understand what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. It was not necessary to fill in *Phase 1* and *Phase 2* fields. I had to install `ipsec-tools` package.

After that, in my case, I also had to stop **xl2tpd** service.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xl2tpd stop
```

Why? Because of this:

> NetworkManager-l2tp starts its own instance of xl2tpd and if the
>   system xl2tpd service is running, its own xl2tpd instance will not be
>   able to use UDP port 1701, so will use an ephemeral port (i.e. random
>   high port).
>
> Although the use of an ephemeral port is considered acceptable in
>   RFC3193, the L2TP/IPsec standard co-authored by Microsoft and Cisco,
>   there are some L2TP/IPsec servers and/or firewalls that will have
>   issues if an ephemeral port is used.

Once I followed these two steps, I tried again to connect and it worked.

Comment: Forvas, I don't suppose you know of a how-to for Kubuntu 18.04 fresh out of the box to connect to a Meraki L2TP VPN? Literally everything I've found either says "try this"...."try that...."..... or, I find articles like this saying something like "nevermind, figured it out" but no actual step-BY-step instructions.

Comment: @00fruX no, I've also tried to find something like that but I wasn't able to. In fact, this VPN connection I talk about in this post stopped to work one random day after several months working. Not only this one but all the connections we had to different VPN. We had to ask for help to our ISP and they had to change our router. After that all the VPN connections started to work again. They just told me our router was too old... No idea what happened there, I'm an Odoo programmer, so VPNs aren't my strength.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I would create one and it would work. I'd follow the exact same instructions to connect to a different exact model of Meraki router and it wouldn't work. Then it'd flip -- the 2nd one would work but not the 1st.  Also the fact that when I did get it working, then disconnect, I would have to completely disable my NIC and re-enable. Very frustrating... guess I will accept the fact L2TP with Meraki routers just don't work yet (and nearly 2020 this is a little hard to believe given how many people use VPNs and how old-ish the Meraki's are).... [turns Windows VM back on :( ] Thanks!